# ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 doesn't recognize .NET Desktop Runtime when deployed through Software Center

Tags: arcgis-pro

We are trying to deploy ArcGIS Pro 3.0.3 as well as the .NET Desktop Runtime prereq through through SCCM. We are able to successfully install the runtime, both versions 6.0.13 and 6.0.5. However, when we then go to try and install ArcGIS Pro through SCCM, the install fails due to it not being able to recognize the runtime.  We have verified successful installation of .NET Desktop runtime by running dotnet --info command.

We've tried with and without adding Runtime as a dependency for ArcGIS Pro.

We've tried on both 6.0.13 and 6.0.5 and are still having the same issues.

Below are logs from AppEnforce. This is without Runtime being a dependency:

+++ Starting Install enforcement for App DT "ArcGIS Pro - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" ApplicationDeliveryType - ScopeId_AD20994E-C291-4497-AD46-F6FB7BDFE106/DeploymentType_5b3bcb04-38cd-47f7-b690-09dbb449be54, Revision - 5, ContentPath - C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\11, Execution Context - Any AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Performing detection of app deployment type ArcGIS Pro - Windows Installer (*.msi file)(ScopeId_AD20994E-C291-4497-AD46-F6FB7BDFE106/DeploymentType_5b3bcb04-38cd-47f7-b690-09dbb449be54, revision 5) for system. AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

+++ MSI application not discovered [MSI Product Code: {690B606E-8A38-4CB9-B088-241F60A86072}, MSI Product version: ] AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

App enforcement environment

```
Context: Machine

Command line: msiexec /i "ArcGISPro.msi" /q

Allow user interaction: No

UI mode: 1

User token: null

Session Id: 1

Content path: C:\\WINDOWS\\ccmcache\\11

Working directory:  AppEnforce  2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM   12408 (0x3078)
```

Prepared working directory: C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\11 AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Found executable file msiexec with complete path C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Prepared command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "ArcGISPro.msi" /q /qn AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:23 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Valid MSI Package path = C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\11\ArcGISPro.msi AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:24 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Advertising MSI package [C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\11\ArcGISPro.msi] to the system. AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:24 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Executing Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "ArcGISPro.msi" /q /qn with user context AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:33 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Working directory C:\WINDOWS\ccmcache\11 AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:33 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Post install behavior is BasedOnExitCode AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:33 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Waiting for process 2840 to finish. Timeout = 120 minutes. AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:33 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Process 2840 terminated with exitcode: 1603 AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:34 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Looking for exit code 1603 in exit codes table... AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:34 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Unmatched exit code (1603) is considered an execution failure. AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:34 AM 12408 (0x3078)

++++++ App enforcement completed (10 seconds) for App DT "ArcGIS Pro - Windows Installer (*.msi file)" [ScopeId_AD20994E-C291-4497-AD46-F6FB7BDFE106/DeploymentType_5b3bcb04-38cd-47f7-b690-09dbb449be54], Revision: 5, User SID: ] ++++++ AppEnforce 2/24/2023 10:52:34 AM 12408 (0x3078)

Has anyone else run into this issue when deploying ArcGIS 3.0.3 though Software Center?

Comment: This one really sounds like a question for ESRI support.

Comment: Haha the only thing ESRI could tell me is make sure you have .NET Desktop Runtime installed.

Comment: .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.14 - patched (64bit) should be installed before ArcGIS Pro with a reboot . https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-desktop-6.0.14-windows-x64-installer will work.

Comment: @HeroicMeatloaf Was that on ESRI forums, or actually logging a support request?  If you log a support request, they should not be closing it until it is resolved.  After you told them that you actually do have it installed, what they say next?

Comment: @SonofaBeach This was a logged support request. It hasn't been closed yet. We have a troubleshooting session today with our SCCM admin. We'll see how it goes.